# Confusion about fiber product in the category of categories.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

The Beauville-Laszlo theorem is a classical result in algebraic geometry. On wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauville%E2%80%93Laszlo_theorem there is a global version of it and it is stated that a certain diagram is a pushout. But the maps are between categories there and given by the restriction of vector bundles. Does this mean that it is a pushout in the category of categories and what does it mean? I know that the idea is that a vectorbundle on an algebraic curve can described by its restriction to a small neighborhood around a rational point and to the curve without that point. But what does it mean formally. Thanks!

Comment: It is meant in the sense of $2$-categories: $\mathcal{X}\times_{F,\mathcal{Y},G}\mathcal{Z}$ has as objects triples $(x,y,f)$ where $x$ is an object of $\mathcal{X}$,  $y$ is an object of $\mathcal{Y}$, and $f\colon F(x)\to G(y)$ is an isomorphism. Morphisms are the obvious things.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Could you elaborate on that? What functors are F and G? I do not know about 2-categories.